# Pointer Lock API prompts

Tags: javascript, html

When on a website using Pointer Lock API it gives a yes/no confirmation when locking the pointer and then succeeding attempts just give a notification.

when on a test with file:/// it never asks for confirmation... is this intended? Should I expect there to be a confirmation if I put my test onto web server?